# XlsxReaderWriter can save my BRAOfficeDocumentPackage using Swift

Tags: swift, xlsx

Hi there friends im trying to edit exelfiles in Swift. I can load a exelfile local from the bundle and save it. But when im downloading the same exel file I can edit it I cant save it. The error message I get is:

Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: '-[BRARelationship contentType] is not implemented in BRARelationship'

```
   do{
     exelIntraUrl = try FileManager.default.url(for: 
     .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask, appropriateFor: nil, 
     create: false).appendingPathComponent("myExelFile.xlsx")
     self.exelIntra = BRAOfficeDocumentPackage.open(exelIntraUrl.path)

     }catch{
        print("some crazy error"        
     }

      self.exelIntra?.save()
```

Im also up for sugestion using some other libary

Comment: Hey, How you did the downloading and saving stuff to the file locally and then read with `BRAOfficeDocumentPackage`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

have you tried:

```
let paths: Array = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.documentDirectory, .userDomainMask, true) as Array
let fullPath: String = paths[0] + "MyFile.xlsx"
print("saving at: \(fullPath)")
worksheet.save()
odp!.save(as: fullPath)
```

Basically, is what the say on their page: [XlsxReaderWriter](https://github.com/renebigot/XlsxReaderWriter)

Comment: Hi there and thanks for the response. The library is dead but is working if you remove some lines in the library.

Comment: the version working for me so far, is: `pod 'XlsxReaderWriter', '~> 2.3.2'`

Comment: Oh then will give you the upvote.didnt work for me when I was using Swift3